# Logging additional information with Debugger.Log call

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

I am trying to log more information about context using `Debug.Log` call in Unity, to debug code an EXP system into my unity game.

I tried to just pass all arguments similar to `String.Format` but as expected got errors like:

> "No overload method 'Log' takes '3' arguments

How can I log additional details along with message?

Code:

```
void Main()
{
    XP xp = new XP(1300);
    Debug.Log("Our character starts at {0} xp and is level {1}.", 
       xp.GetCurrentXp(), xp.GetCurrentLevel());
    Debug.Log("Now, we add 2000 xp.");
    xp.AddXp(2000);
    Debug.Log("Now, our character has {0} xp and is level {1}.", 
       xp.GetCurrentXp(), xp.GetCurrentLevel());
    Debug.Log("Our character is {0}% in to his next level", 
       xp.GetPercentInToLevel() * 100f);
}
```

[image: errors]

Comment: [Unity3d Debug.Log](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) have only 1 and 2 arguments versions - not exactly sure how do you expect this code to compile. Possibly suggestion by Phenix_you to use `String.Format` is what you are after, but without more details looks like candidate to close.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed [Debug.Log](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) only have overrides with 1 and 2 arguments (scripting API):

```
public static function Log(message: object): void;
public static function Log(message: object, context: Object): void;
```

You may want to use `String.Format` to construct message:

```
Debug.Log(string.Format("Our character starts at {0} xp and is level {1}.", 
      xp.GetCurrentXp(), xp.GetCurrentLevel()));
```

Comment: @JamesShaw: Did you read that link?  There is no overload to `Log()` that has three parameters.

Comment: No Log function take three parameters:
public static function Log(message: object): void;
public static function Log(message: object, context: Object): void;